# enumerate all combinations in c++

Tags: c++, iterator, combinations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Howto create combinations of several vectors without hardcoding loops in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700079/howto-create-combinations-of-several-vectors-without-hardcoding-loops-in-c)

My question is similar to [this combinations question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678596/enumerating-all-combinations-of-lists-of-different-types) but in my case I have N (N > 4) small sets (1-2 items per set for now might go to 3 maybe 4) and want to generate each combination of one item from each set.

The current solution looks somethinging along the lines of this

```
for(T:: iterator a = setA.begin(); a != setA.end(); ++a) 
 for(T:: iterator b = setB.begin(); b != setB.end(); ++b) 
  for(T:: iterator c = setC.begin(); c != setC.end(); ++c) 
   for(T:: iterator d = setD.begin(); d != setD.end(); ++d) 
    for(T:: iterator e = setE.begin(); e != setE.end(); ++e)
     something(*a,*b,*c,*d,*e);
```

Simple, effective, probably reasonably efficient, but ugly and not very extensible. Does anyone know of a better/cleaner way to do this that is just as fast?

An ideal solution would look like a single loop and come from some well supported library.

```
Combinations<T> comb;
comb.set(0) = setA;
comb.set(1) = setB;
comb.set(2) = setC;
comb.set(3) = setD;
comb.set(4) = setE;

for(Combinations<T>::iterator a = comb.begin(); a != comb.end(); ++a) 
  something(*a[0],*a[1],*a[2],*a[3],*a[4]);
```

Comment: I like Sumudu Fernando's solution to that question

Answer (score 1):

If you need raw performance (=>no recursion) and length of the combination is known only at runtime, there's [this code of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991361/find-all-combinations-of-a-given-set-of-numbers/1991542#1991542) that you can adapt.

Otherwise, there are more elegant solutions like the ones linked by KennyTM in his comment.